# Firebase does not return data when requested from vuejs

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, firebase-realtime-database, vuex

There are records of the following type in my firebase database

```
{
    "profiles": {
        "py5rBNf45PSjS5SC319xB4dn8OC3": {
            "balance": 0,
            "nickName": 3,
            "firstName": 3,
            "secondName": "",
            "lastName": "",
            "country": "",
            "city": "",
            "home": "",
            "phone": "",
            "signUpDate": "",
            "verified": false,
            "goToVerified": false,
            "turnover": 85,
            "lusingTrade": 0,
            "profitTrade": 0,
            "lastPaymentDate": 0,
        }
    }
}
```

I need to get to this data. I do it like this in my vuex file

```
fbProfileReadData({commit}, userId){
        let userProfile = firebaseDb.ref('profies/'+userId)
        alert(userProfile)

        userProfile.once('value', snapshot => {
            commit('setFbProfileReadData', true)
            let testVal = snapshot.val()
            console.log(testVal) // I see null here
        }, error => {
            showErrorMessage(error.message)
        })
        console.log("FB PROFILE READ DATA")
},
```

But I am not getting the data I need, even though the snapshot object is being created and I do not see the request error. What am I doing wrong? How do I fix the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have mistyped `profiles` as `profies` at

```
let userProfile = firebaseDb.ref('profies/'+userId)
```

You can add some basic security rules, not only for security, but to spot errors like this one.

Comment: Oh mate! I'm stupid. Thank you! It's work! 

I just started to learn the platform and at the same time I have to learn quasar ... 

Can you guide me on how to identify such errors using rules? At the moment, it is the rule management that is the most incomprehensible to me.

Comment: @EthicalHacking if your rules allowed reading at "profiles" instead of root, you'd get a helpful `Permission denied at "profies"` error. Read the docs, they cover the basics well. I also like predefining most db refs as constants, so that I won't risk mistyping them.

Comment: Thank you mate!!